# Using Reflection in .NET 3.0

Tags: c#

I have an class

```
public class UserType
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public string EmailAddress;
    public VehicleType Vehicle;
    public AddressType Address;
    public JobType Job;
}

public class VehicleType
{
    public string Make;
    public string Model;
}

public class AddressType
{
    public string HouseNumber;
    public string StreetName;
    public string Town;
    public string PostCode;
}

public class JobType
{
    public string Description;
    public int Salary;
    public ManagerType Manager;
    public DepartmentType Department;
}

public class ManagerType
{
    public string Name;
    public ManagerType Manager;
}

public class DepartmentType
{
    public string Name;
    public BuildingType Building;
}

public class BuildingType
{
    public string Name;
    public AddressType Address;
}
```

I need to write a recursion program which has to populate these classes from the xml using reflection.

the input is the xml which would get the value and update it to t class. If it is a simple type then it works but for complext type the object is lost.
I have highlighted where the issue is. This code has to work in C#3.5

```
private static object GetObject(string typeName, string propertyName, XmlNode inputs, Assembly assembly )
{
    var type = assembly.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == typeName);
    if (type == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type {0} is not found.", typeName));

    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(inputs.OuterXml);
    string childNode = "";
    foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.SetProperty))
    {
        if (!prop.Name.Equals("ExtensionData"))
        {
            //prop.SetValue(obj,
            //              prop.PropertyType.IsPrimitive()
            //                  ? inputs[propertyName].ChildNodes[0].Value
            //                  : GetObject(prop.PropertyType.Name, prop.PropertyType.Name, inputs, assembly), null);

            if (prop.PropertyType.IsPrimitive())
            {
                var childNodesPropLst = doc.Descendants(propertyName);
                foreach (XElement childNodeprop in childNodesPropLst)
                {
                    XElement childElement = childNodeprop.Element(prop.Name);
                    if (childElement != null)
                    {
                        childNode = childElement.Value;
                        prop.SetValue(obj, childNode, null);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                **GetObject(prop.PropertyType.Name, prop.Name, inputs, assembly);**
            }
            //prop.SetValue(obj, childNode, null);
        }
    }

    return obj;            
}
```

My current program supports C#3.0.

```
<Inputs> <User> <FirstName>String</FirstName> <LastName>String</LastName> <EmailAddress>String</EmailAddress> <Vehicle> <Make>String</Make> <Model>String</Model> </Vehicle> <Address> <HouseNumber>String</HouseNumber> <StreetName>String</StreetName> <Town>String</Town> <PostCode>String</PostCode> </Address><Job> <Description>String</Description> <Salary>32</Salary> <Manager> <Name>String</Name> <Manager></Manager> </Manager> <Department> <Name>String</Name> <Building> <Name>String</Name> <Address> <HouseNumber>String</HouseNumber> <StreetName>String</StreetName> <Town>String</Town> <PostCode>String</PostCode> </Address> </Building> </Department> </Job> </User></Inputs>
```

Comment: You want to look at the source code for `DataContractSerializer` or `XmlSerializer`. Check here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: Do you have an example of the XML you are parsing?

Comment: XML Example
<Inputs>
<User>
    <FirstName>String</FirstName>
    <LastName>String</LastName>
    <EmailAddress>String</EmailAddress>
    <Vehicle>
      <Make>String</Make>
      <Model>String</Model>
    </Vehicle>
    <Address>
      <HouseNumber>String</HouseNumber>
      <StreetName>String</StreetName>
      <Town>String</Town>
      <PostCode>String</PostCode>
    </Address>
<Job></Job>
</Inputs>

Comment: sorry forgot to add the values for Job Element in the previous xml
<Job>
      <Description>String</Description>
      <Salary>32</Salary>
      <Manager>
        <Name>String</Name>
        <Manager></Manager>
      </Manager>
      <Department>
        <Name>String</Name>
        <Building>
          <Name>String</Name>
          <Address>
            <HouseNumber>String</HouseNumber>
            <StreetName>String</StreetName>
            <Town>String</Town>
            <PostCode>String</PostCode>
          </Address>
        </Building>
      </Department>
    </Job>
  </User>

Comment: Add the XML to your question, not to comments.

Comment: Also, you seem to be talking about .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5. The language version is not related to the .NET version. Also, there is no C# 3.5.

Comment: Just in case you don't realize what John means with "Add the XML to your question, not to comments.", he's saying you should _edit_ your question and add the extra information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have highlighted the `GetObject()` method but do nothing with its return value. What about:

```
object propVal = GetObject(prop.PropertyType.Name, prop.Name, inputs, assembly);
prop.SetValue(obj, propVal, null);
```

Comment: Tried doing this but Not wrorking. any way what i need to do is that getting the value from this xml for example <FirstName>String</FirstName> and populating this to the class username.Firstname. This works for Primitive type but when complex type comes like vehicle i am not sure what to do. this vehicle object is not getting assigned to user class.

Comment: `prop.SetValue()` assigns an object to a property of the parent class - which seems to me is exactly what's missing in your code. Can you be more specific than "not working" to describe your issue when you use the code from my answer? Any exceptions that occur, for instance?

Comment: Thanks Evenhuis the initial one worked. Now when you look on the class definition that has been specified there is a class known as "ManagerType" and it has two properties Name and Manager. The name is of string where as the Manager is of type "ManageType" hence it goes in a loop. As told thanks for your help i am not sure what can i do with this.

Comment: I need a help for a scenario like the one specified below. I have a class ManagerType which has two property Name and Manager. The manager return type is of Manager. I am using reflections in the code. This goes in to a loop . The code and the class is specified above. Much appreciated if some one can help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static object GetObject(string typeName, string propertyName, XmlNode inputs, Assembly assembly)
    {

        var type = assembly.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == typeName);
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type {0} is not found.", typeName));
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(inputs.OuterXml);

        foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.SetProperty))
        {
            if (!prop.Name.Equals("ExtensionData"))
            { 
                if (prop.PropertyType.IsPrimitive())
                {
                    var childNodesPropLst = doc.Descendants(propertyName);
                    foreach (XElement childNodeprop in childNodesPropLst)
                    {
                        XElement childElement = childNodeprop.Element(prop.Name);
                        if (childElement != null)
                        {
                            prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(childElement.Value, prop.PropertyType), null);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // This is done if the return type of the property belongs to the same class name.
                    // Otherwise it goes in a loop.
                    if (prop.PropertyType.Name.Equals(type.Name))
                        break;
                    Object propVal = GetObject(prop.PropertyType.Name, prop.Name, inputs, assembly);
                    prop.SetValue(obj, propVal, null);

                }

                //prop.SetValue(obj,childNode,null);
            }
        }

        foreach (var f in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.SetField))
        {
            f.SetValue(obj,
                       f.FieldType.IsPrimitive()
                           ? inputs[propertyName].ChildNodes[0].Value
                           : GetObject(f.FieldType.Name, f.FieldType.Name, inputs, assembly));
        }
        return obj;
    }
```